# Is it safe to pass a va_list to another function without using va_copy?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, c99, variadic-functions

[This blog post](http://julipedia.meroh.net/2011/09/using-vacopy-to-safely-pass-ap.html) claims that passing a `va_list` to another function like in the following code is unsafe, and that the `va_list` must first be copied using `va_copy`:

```
void
foo_ap(const char *fmt, va_list ap)
{
    char buf[128];

    vsnprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), fmt, ap);

    // now, do something with buf ...
}
```

Like one of the comments to the blog post mentions, I can't see how this would be unsafe, as the C99 spec states (7.15):

> The object `ap` may be passed as an argument to another function; if that function invokes the `va_arg` macro with parameter `ap`, the value of `ap` in the calling function is indeterminate and shall be passed to the `va_end` macro prior to any further reference to `ap`.

(As long as `foo_ap` doesn't reference `ap` after passing it on, the second part of the sentence doesn't seem to apply anyway.) The author of the blog post says in another comment that he might be wrong, but maybe someone can add some clarification. Do I really have to use `va_copy` to be on the safe side? Or are there any platforms that don't conform to the spec and require the use of `va_copy`?

Comment: The blog post seems to directly contradict the clause you cited from the C99 standard.  The blog author does say "A long time ago" at the start of it, so my guess is that he was dealing with some old, non-standards-conformant system.

Comment: You only need `va_copy` if you still plan to use `ap` after `vsnprintf` returns. For example, you might want to call `vsnprintf` twice - once to determined the required buffer size, and again to format for real. If you don't need to use `ap` again except for passing it to `va_end`, then you don't need to `va_copy` it.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik If you make your comment an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You only need `va_copy` if you still plan to use `ap` after `vsnprintf` returns. For example, you might want to call `vsnprintf` twice - once to determine the required buffer size, and again to format for real. If you don't need to use `ap` again (except perhaps for passing it to `va_end`, if you were the one creating it with `va_start`), then you don't need to `va_copy` it.

Comment: I've observed implementations where a va_list behaves as though passed by value [so arguments consumed by a function that receives it come back into existence when that function returns], and others where it behaves as though passed by reference [the arguments remain consumed].  Problems with using a va_list after calling a method which also uses it are thus not merely "theoretical".